# Get meta title and description with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the meta title and description from any website I add into the URL field. What am I missing here? If I put something in the URL field and click fetch it nothing appears. When I put say "https://www.espn.com/" for the URL within the JS function it's pulling the whole website into the preview.

What am I missing?

```js
//DISPLAY META
$(document).ready(function() {
 
    $('.seoTitle').on('keyup', function() {
      $('.seoTitleNew').text($(this).val());
    });
  
    $('.seoMeta').on('keyup', function() {
      $('.seoMetaNew').text($(this).val());
    });
  
});
//END DISPLAY META


//GET URL META
function myMetaFunction() {
 var url = document.getElementById("seoUrlFetch").innerHTML;
  //if you try "https://www.espn.com/" below for url it pulls in the whole page
  $.get(url, function(data) {
      $(data).filter('meta[property="og:title"]').attr("content");

      document.getElementById("seoTitleDisplay").innerHTML = data;
  }); 
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <span>URL </span><input type="text" id="seoUrlFetch" class="seoURL" placeholder="Enter single URL or paste multiple URLs to fetch data from..." autocapitalize="none"> <button id="fetchURLButton" onclick="myMetaFunction()">Fetch</button>
  </div>

  <div>
     <span>Title </span><input class="seoTitle" type="text" placeholder="Your title..." autocapitalize="none">
  </div>

  <div>
     <span>Meta </span><textarea class="seoMeta" type="text" placeholder="Your meta description..." autocapitalize="none"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <p id="seoTitleDisplay" class="seoTitleNew"></p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <span class="seoMetaNew"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, you're going to have CORS issues. Aside from that though, why should it not put all the content there? `document.getElementById("seoTitleDisplay").innerHTML = data;` says "put `data` (the whole page content response) into this element".

Comment: @Chase Well I guess I thought I was only pulling the Title of the page and not the whole page within the 'data' .. Is there a better way to extract the meta data?

Comment: The first thing you need is the *value* of the entry, not the innerHTML, so, `var url = document.getElementById("seoUrlFetch").value;`. I didn't look at anything after that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting the innerHTML to the entire returned document.

Based on jquery's documentation, the filter function will not mutate the original argument you pass to it -- it constructs a new jquery object that is filtered (https://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Try the following

```
const filteredData = $(data).filter('meta[property="og:title"]').attr("content");

document.getElementById("seoTitleDisplay").innerHTML = filteredData;
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I add that info the function it returns undefined.